# date format in java

Tags: java

My requirement is to get the date in format `MM/dd/yy`. But I am currently getting the date value as "Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2006". I tried a sample code for the conversion as follows.

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
  try {
    Date date = format.parse("12/31/2006");
    System.out.println(date);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Please help me to convert the given date into `MM/dd/yy`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use SDF ([SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) to process the output too.

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy"; 
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern); 
  try { 
    Date date = format.parse("12/31/2006"); 
    System.out.println(format.format(date)); 
  } catch (ParseException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks yock and everyone. The above said code works well. Have gained a lot regarding date. Am selecting this as a=my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
String pattern = ;
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
try {
    Date date = inputFormat.parse("12/31/2006");
    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
 } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of your output is because you're outputting the date object through `System.out.println(date);` which is effectively, translated to `System.out.println(date.toString());`

The `toString()` method of `Date` outputs date in the format of:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

Here's the code for `Date.toString()`

```
public String toString() {
    // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
    int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
    if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
        index = 8;
    }
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');            // EEE
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
    TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
    if (zi != null) {
        sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), zi.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
    } else {
        sb.append("GMT");
    }
    sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
    return sb.toString();
    }
```

Your code is correct though. Use `SimpleDateFormat` to display the date like so:

```
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `SimpleDateFormat` to *parse* a string, and that's working fine - but then you're using `Date`'s toString method (implicitly) when *formatting* the date. That will use a default format which is completely independent of the format which was originally used to parse the value.

A `Date` object knows *nothing* about how you want to format it. That's what you should be using `SimpleDateFormat` for.

You *can* use `SimpleDateFormat` to format it again:

```
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

... but a better approach would be to switch to [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and use its [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class, which is thread-safe and immutable, unlike `SimpleDateFormat`... the rest of its API is better, too.